# facebook app stops at "got to facebook" in IE

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

when users fist come to my Facebook App in IE they are getting the Go to Facebook link witch  sends them to the authorize url(dialog). all other browsers redirect to the authorize url automatic except ie ?? what can i do to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most IE issues with login are due to the fact that IE really loves to see a p3p header from your website before it will play nice with the cookies that facebook tries to set.  Ensure your server is serving out a p3p policy.

Comment: Sorry my question was so generic. This ended up not being how I fixed my issue but that is because I asked the question wrong and did not provide enough detail sorry but thanks :) so yes this is the most correct answer to what I asked

Answer (score 0):

You question lacks information. If you do the redirect server-side instead of in JavaScript it should work.